# Cómo puedo editar llave foranea CRUD jpa jsf?

Tags: java, jsf, jpa, ejb

Al traer lo datos de la tabla, aparece en el formato correcto. Si edito una fila en la tabla `Registros`, aparece un error porque tengo la llave foránea `IdVehículo`:

```
javax.faces.el.EvaluationException: javax.ejb.EJBException

javax.validation.ConstraintViolationException: Bean Validation constraint(s) violated while executing Automatic Bean Validation on callback event:'prePersist'. Please refer to embedded ConstraintViolations for details.
```

Este es el log del **Glassfish**:

```
[2018-05-24T22:00:37.848-0500] [glassfish 4.1] [WARNING] [] [javax.enterprise.web] [tid: _ThreadID=207 _ThreadName=http-listener-1(3)] [timeMillis: 1527217237848] [levelValue: 900] 
[[StandardWrapperValve[Faces Servlet]: Servlet.service() for servlet Faces Servlet threw exception

javax.validation.ConstraintViolationException: Bean Validation constraint(s) violated while executing Automatic Bean Validation on callback event:'prePersist'. Please refer to embedded ConstraintViolations for details.
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.metadata.listeners.BeanValidationListener.validateOnCallbackEvent(BeanValidationListener.java:108)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.metadata.listeners.BeanValidationListener.prePersist(BeanValidationListener.java:77)
at org.eclipse.persistence.descriptors.DescriptorEventManager.notifyListener(DescriptorEventManager.java:748)
at org.eclipse.persistence.descriptors.DescriptorEventManager.notifyEJB30Listeners(DescriptorEventManager.java:691)
at org.eclipse.persistence.descriptors.DescriptorEventManager.executeEvent(DescriptorEventManager.java:229)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.registerNewObjectClone(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:4314)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.RepeatableWriteUnitOfWork.cloneAndRegisterNewObject(RepeatableWriteUnitOfWork.java:611)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.internalRegisterObject(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:2937)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.MergeManager.registerObjectForMergeCloneIntoWorkingCopy(MergeManager.java:1087)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.MergeManager.mergeChangesOfCloneIntoWorkingCopy(MergeManager.java:557)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.MergeManager.mergeChanges(MergeManager.java:313)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.mergeCloneWithReferences(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:3521)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.RepeatableWriteUnitOfWork.mergeCloneWithReferences(RepeatableWriteUnitOfWork.java:387)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.mergeCloneWithReferences(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:3481)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerImpl.mergeInternal(EntityManagerImpl.java:553)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerImpl.merge(EntityManagerImpl.java:530)
at com.sun.enterprise.container.common.impl.EntityManagerWrapper.merge(EntityManagerWrapper.java:305)
at logica.AbstractFacade.edit(AbstractFacade.java:40)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.glassfish.ejb.security.application.EJBSecurityManager.runMethod(EJBSecurityManager.java:1081)
at org.glassfish.ejb.security.application.EJBSecurityManager.invoke(EJBSecurityManager.java:1153)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.invokeBeanMethod(BaseContainer.java:4786)
at com.sun.ejb.EjbInvocation.invokeBeanMethod(EjbInvocation.java:656)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeChainImpl.invokeNext(InterceptorManager.java:822)
at com.sun.ejb.EjbInvocation.proceed(EjbInvocation.java:608)
at org.jboss.weld.ejb.AbstractEJBRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.aroundInvoke(AbstractEJBRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.java:64)
at org.jboss.weld.ejb.SessionBeanInterceptor.aroundInvoke(SessionBeanInterceptor.java:52)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor199.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeInterceptor.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:883)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeChainImpl.invokeNext(InterceptorManager.java:822)
at com.sun.ejb.EjbInvocation.proceed(EjbInvocation.java:608)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.SystemInterceptorProxy.doCall(SystemInterceptorProxy.java:163)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.SystemInterceptorProxy.aroundInvoke(SystemInterceptorProxy.java:140)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor200.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeInterceptor.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:883)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeChainImpl.invokeNext(InterceptorManager.java:822)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.InterceptorManager.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:369)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.__intercept(BaseContainer.java:4758)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.intercept(BaseContainer.java:4746)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.invoke(EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.java:212)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandlerDelegate.invoke(EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandlerDelegate.java:88)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy404.edit(Unknown Source)
at logica.__EJB31_Generated__RegistrosFacade__Intf____Bean__.edit(Unknown Source)
at controlador.RegistroController.GuardarEdicion(RegistroController.java:175)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at javax.el.ELUtil.invokeMethod(ELUtil.java:332)
at javax.el.BeanELResolver.invoke(BeanELResolver.java:537)
at javax.el.CompositeELResolver.invoke(CompositeELResolver.java:256)
at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:283)
at com.sun.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:304)
at org.jboss.weld.util.el.ForwardingMethodExpression.invoke(ForwardingMethodExpression.java:40)
at org.jboss.weld.el.WeldMethodExpression.invoke(WeldMethodExpression.java:50)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:105)
at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:87)
at com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:102)
at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:315)
at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:790)
at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1282)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:81)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:198)
at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:658)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1682)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:318)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:734)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:673)
at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:174)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:416)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:283)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:459)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:167)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:206)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:180)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:235)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:283)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:200)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:132)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:111)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:536)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:591)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:571)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
]]
```

Esto es `RegistroBean`, el método `GuardarEdicion()` es el que produce el error, pero no entiendo lo que puede estar causando.

```
public String Editar(Integer id){
  Registros r=this.registrosFacade.find(id);
  DateFormat dateFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");  
  this.fecha=dateFormatter.format(r.getFecha());
  DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss 'Z'");  
  dateFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));    
  this.hora_in= dateFormat.format(r.getHoraIn());
  this.hora_out= dateFormat.format(r.getHoraOut());
  this.vehiculo=r.getIdVehiculo();
  return "RegistroEdit";
}

public String GuardarEdicion(RegistroController rc, int id) throws ParseException{
Registros r = new Registros();
  Locale locale = new Locale("es","CO");
  String datef = "MM/dd/yyyy";
  SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat(datef, locale);
  Date parsedDate = formatter.parse(fecha);
  r.setFecha(parsedDate);
  String hourf = "HH:mm:ss 'Z'";
  SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat(hourf, locale);
  format.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));
  Date Hin = format.parse(hora_in);
  r.setHoraIn(Hin);
  Date Hout = format.parse(hora_out);
  r.setHoraOut(Hout);
  r.setIdVehiculo(vehiculosFacade.find(vehiculo.getId()));
  this.registrosFacade.edit(r);
  return "RegistroList";
}
```

Este es **RegistroEdit.xhtml**:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
  xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core"
  xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
  xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets">
<h:head>
    <title>Facelet Title</title>
</h:head>
<h:body>
    <f:view>


        <h:form>
            <h1><h:outputText value="Editar Registro"/></h1>
            <p:panelGrid columns="2">

                <p:outputLabel value="Fecha:" for="fecha" />
                <p:inputText id="fecha" value="#{registroBean.fecha}" title="Fecha" >

                </p:inputText>
                <p:outputLabel value="HoraIn:" for="horaIn" />
                <p:inputText id="horaIn" value="#{registroBean.hora_in}" title="HoraIn" required="true" requiredMessage="The HoraIn field is required.">

                </p:inputText>
                <p:outputLabel value="HoraOut:" for="horaOut" />
                <p:inputText id="horaOut" value="#{registroBean.hora_out}" title="HoraOut" required="true" requiredMessage="The HoraOut field is required.">

                </p:inputText>
                <p:outputLabel value="IdVehiculo:" for="idVehiculo" />
                <p:selectOneMenu id="idVehiculo" value="#{registroBean.vehiculo.id}" required="true" requiredMessage="The IdVehiculo field is required.">
                    <!-- TODO: update below reference to list of available items-->
                    <f:selectItems value="#{vehiculoBean.findAll()}" var="v" itemLabel="#{v.placa}" itemValue="#{v.id}"/>
                </p:selectOneMenu>
            </p:panelGrid>
            <h:panelGrid columns="2">
             <h:commandButton id="registroCommand" value="Guardar"
                              action="#{registroBean.GuardarEdicion(registroBean, registroBean.id)}"/>          
            <h:commandButton id="registroCommand1" value="Ir a Lista"
                             action="#{registroBean.prepareList()}"/> 
          </h:panelGrid>
        </h:form>
    </f:view>

</h:body>
</html>
```

¿Qué debo cambiar para poder editar la clave externa, y no aparezca el error?